# Error: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am currently creating some app using `tkinter` and the problem is that one of the label widgets is returning an error given in the title. I have also made other labels in the same GUI they are working perfect but this one is returning a problem. Here is the code if anyone can tell:

```
from tkinter import *
import platform
root = Tk()
if platform.system() == "Windows" or platform.system() == "MacOS" or platform.system() == "Linux" or platform.system() == "Unix" or platform.system() == "Darwin":
    root.geometry("500x750")
    root.minsize(500, 750)
    root.maxsize(500, 750)
    root.config(bg="red")
    title = Frame(root, width=500, height=100, bg="red")
    Label(title, text="MultiTables", font="Chalkduster 40", bg="red").pack()
    title.pack()
    f1 = Frame(root, width=300, height=200, bg="red")

    def get_table():
        if len(str(table_number_store.get())) > 8:
            return Label(f1, "Please enter a smaller number. Maximum number length is 8", bg="red", fg="blue").pack(fill=BOTH)
            
        try:
            new_number = int(table_number_store.get())
        except Exception:
            Label(f1, text="Please enter only numbers and not other symbols or letters",
                  fg="blue", bg="red").pack(fill=BOTH)
        else:
            f1.destroy()
            f2 = Frame(root, width=1000, height=700, bg="red")
            for i in range(1, 11):
                Label(f2, text=f"{table_number_store.get()}×{i}={table_number_store.get()*i}", font=(
                    "American Typewriter", 40), fg="#D2B48C", bg="red").pack(pady=3, fill=Y)
            f2.pack(fill=BOTH, pady=40)

    # try:
    table_number_store = IntVar()
    table_number = Entry(f1, insertbackground="black",
                         textvariable=table_number_store)
    table_number.pack(pady=10, fill=BOTH, anchor="center", padx=30)
    button = Button(f1, text="Get my table", height=1, font=("American Typewriter", 20),
                    highlightbackground="red", command=get_table).pack(fill=BOTH, padx=150)
    f1.pack(fill=BOTH, pady=275)
    # except Exception:
    #     Label(f1, text="Please enter only numbers and not other symbols or letters", fg="blue", bg="red").pack(fill=BOTH)
else:
    root.geometry(f"{root.winfo_screenwidth()}x{root.winfo_screenheight()}")
    root.config(bg="red")
    f1 = Frame(root, width=root.winfo_screenwidth(), height=200, bg="red")


    def get_table():
        try:
            new_number = int(table_number_store.get())
        except Exception:
            Label(f1, text="Please enter only numbers and not other symbols or letters",
                  fg="blue", bg="black").pack(fill=BOTH)
        else:
            f1.destroy()
            f2 = Frame(root, width=1000, height=700, bg="red")
            for i in range(1, 11):
                Label(f2, text=f"{table_number_store.get()}×{i}={table_number_store.get()*i}", font=(
                    "American Typewriter", 50), fg="#D2B48C", bg="red").pack(pady=3, fill=Y)
            f2.pack(fill=BOTH)

    # try:
    table_number_store = IntVar()
    table_number = Entry(f1, insertbackground="black",
                         textvariable=table_number_store)
    table_number.pack(pady=10, fill=BOTH, anchor="center", padx=30)
    button = Button(f1, text="Get my table", height=1, font=("American Typewriter", 20),
                    highlightbackground="red", command=get_table).pack(fill=BOTH, padx=150)
    f1.pack(fill=BOTH, pady=300)
root.mainloop()
```

I tried creating an app using `tkinter` and it was just about to finish when this problem occurred. Please help if anyone can.

Comment: Can you give us the full traceback?

Comment: `Label(f1, "Please enter a smaller number. Maximum number length is 8", bg="red", fg="blue")` should be `Label(f1, text="Please enter a smaller number. Maximum number length is 8", bg="red", fg="blue")`.